# Returning query/table into a variable

Tags: sql, postgresql, ubuntu-18.04, psql

Following the instructions from [here](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-user-defined-functions/sql-server-table-valued-functions/), I am trying to return the results of a query into a variable like so

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE DATABASE test;

\c test

CREATE TABLE staff(
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name   VARCHAR(50),
    last_name    VARCHAR(50),
    age          SMALLINT
);

CREATE FUNCTION get_contacts(
    p_id_min  BIGINT,
    p_id_max  BIGINT,
    p_age_min BIGINT,
    p_age_max BIGINT
)
    RETURNS @contacts TABLE (
        first_name VARCHAR(50),
        last_name  VARCHAR(50)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @contacts
    SELECT 
        first_name, 
        last_name
    FROM
        staff
    WHERE
        id >= p_id_min
    AND
        id <= p_id_max;

    INSERT INTO @contacts
    SELECT 
        first_name, 
        last_name
    FROM
        staff
    WHERE
        age >= p_age_min
    AND
        age <= p_age_max;

    RETURN;
END;
```

But I am getting the following error

```
DROP DATABASE
CREATE DATABASE
You are now connected to database "test" as user "postgres".
CREATE TABLE
psql:test.sql:31: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "@"
LINE 5:     RETURNS @contacts TABLE (
                    ^
psql:test.sql:33: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "RETURN"
LINE 1: RETURN;
        ^
psql:test.sql:34: WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress
COMMIT
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Why am I getting the `syntax error at or near "@"` and how do I fix thix?
2. What is the significance of `@` at the beginning of a variable name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, in Postgres, the `RETURN` command can be used multiple times, so I just did the following

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_contacts(
    p_id_min  BIGINT,
    p_id_max  BIGINT,
    p_age_min BIGINT,
    p_age_max BIGINT
)
RETURNS TABLE(
    id          BIGINT,
    first_name  VARCHAR(50),
    last_name   VARCHAR(50),
    age         SMALLINT
)
AS $$
BEGIN
    --RETURN FIRST QUERY
    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT * FROM staff
        WHERE id >=p_id_min AND id<=p_id_max;

    --DO OTHER WORK
    ...

    --RETURN SECOND QUERY
    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT * FROM staff
        WHERE age >=p_age_min AND age<=p_age_max;
END $$ LAnguage 'plpgsql';
```

Answer (score 0):

Author was initially using @ for parameters. For code you might also try this

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_contacts(
p_id_min  BIGINT,
p_id_max  BIGINT,
p_age_min BIGINT,
p_age_max BIGINT
)
RETURNS TABLE (
    first_name VARCHAR(50),
    last_name  VARCHAR(50)
)
AS $$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @contacts
SELECT 
    first_name, 
    last_name
FROM
    staff
WHERE
    id >= p_id_min
AND
    id <= p_id_max;

INSERT INTO @contacts
SELECT 
    first_name, 
    last_name
FROM
    staff
WHERE
    age >= p_age_min
AND
    age <= p_age_max;

RETURN;
END;
```